# Override django contrib auth locales

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-i18n

I am using the login and registration views from `django.contrib.auth` 
But now I want to implement custom translations. 
How can I get the messages from there to my translation file which I created using 
`./manage.py makemessages -a`

Comment: So the question is how to import translation feature in login/registration Views right ?

Comment: Yes. I want to create my own translations for login views